# Can I restrict user's access on a certain IP?

Tags: mongodb

Like in a certain way in MySQL.

`CREATE 'dbuser'@'10.1.0.1' identitifed by 'password';`

`GRANT USAGE on *.* to 'dbuser'@'10.1.0.1';`

We are not using any mongodb tools except for Robo

Answer (score 0):

When you create a user then you can specify [Authentication Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/index.html#authentication-restrictions)

Would be like this:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "dbuser",
     pwd: "password"
     roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "reporting" } ],
     authenticationRestrictions: [ {
        clientSource: ["192.0.2.0"],
        serverAddress: ["198.51.100.0"]
     } ]
   }
)
```

But for me it is not clear, if you are looking for this.

Comment: Hi Wenfried. Considering the reporting machine is the clientSource(192.0.2.0)

How can I restrict this 192.0.2.0 from using any other user apart from dbuser? Like the mongo user that our app is using.

Comment: I don't think you can do it. If someone has other credentials (e.g. let's say admin user) then he can connect to your DB. Actually you cannot prevent the user to use any other client (e.g. the mongo shell) for connection. You cannot force him to use only your application.

Comment: @Wenfried like for example i have a user with clientSource: ["10.1.0.0/16", "127.0.0.1"]
cant I restrict 1 IP from 10.1.0.0/16? Lets say 10.1.0.23

Comment: I thought of a workaround like indicating all IP within the CIDR block of 10.1.0.0/16 but it is messy.

Comment: @JRA `clientSource` restrictions can be an array of IP addresses and/or CIDR ranges, so you can set up appropriate restrctions per MongoDB user. To prevent 192.0.2.0 from authenticating with any credentials other than `dbuser`, you would make sure this IP isn't included in the `clientSource` addresses or ranges for other users. Where possible I would also limit guest access to interacting via an API rather than providing direct access to your MongoDB deployment.

Answer (score -3):

In mongodb config file, you should specify bind_address value to your desired ip.

Comment: I cannot see that parameter in the documentation, and even if it exists, it will contain the server's IP address, not the client's.

Comment: i think this is not it. i dont want to bind_address to a specific IP. I just want to know if there can be restriction to a specific mongodb user to a certain IP. The scenario is this: we have a guest VM where the users can extract data. that VM's vnet is within our Production VNET. now the risk is if the guest user somehow able to know the mongodb credentials of our app's mongodb. Then the data is exposed and can be manipulated. In MySQL, even if that guest user was able to connect on our Prod VM, by executing "GRANT USAGE app_user@10.1.0.1;" he wont see anything on the Database.

Comment: @JRA You can create a new user with `read privilege` on the specific db alone and share it so that the user won't see any other data. Is there any particular for an IP restriction?